# Choose an item from a column / row in a Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with AWS and have a list of the AWS regions and their corresponding Opt-in Status. This is in a dictionary called `region_dict`:

```
{
    'eu-north-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'ap-south-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'eu-west-3': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'eu-west-2': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'eu-west-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'ap-northeast-2': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'ap-northeast-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'sa-east-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'ca-central-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'ap-southeast-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'ap-southeast-2': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'eu-central-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'us-east-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'us-east-2': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'us-west-1': 'opt-in-not-required',
    'us-west-2': 'opt-in-not-required',
}
```

I am using a Pandas dataframe to display the data:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(region_dict.items(), columns = ['Region', 'Opt-in Status'])
dataframe.index += 1
print(dataframe)


            Region        Opt-in Status
1       eu-north-1  opt-in-not-required
2       ap-south-1  opt-in-not-required
3        eu-west-3  opt-in-not-required
4        eu-west-2  opt-in-not-required
5        eu-west-1  opt-in-not-required
6   ap-northeast-2  opt-in-not-required
7   ap-northeast-1  opt-in-not-required
8        sa-east-1  opt-in-not-required
9     ca-central-1  opt-in-not-required
10  ap-southeast-1  opt-in-not-required
11  ap-southeast-2  opt-in-not-required
12    eu-central-1  opt-in-not-required
13       us-east-1  opt-in-not-required
14       us-east-2  opt-in-not-required
15       us-west-1  opt-in-not-required
16       us-west-2  opt-in-not-required
```

I'd like to ask the user which region he wants to use:

```
region = input("Enter the number of the region to use: ")
```

Once I get the integer, how can I go through the dictionary and figure out which region the integer input responds to? Beginner programmer here, so I'm reaching out to you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number of the region corresponds to the index in the dataframe, you could use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). To get the entire row, you could use

```
dataframe.iloc[region]
```

If you wanted only first column (ie. the region name), you could instead use

```
dataframe.iloc[region, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks. The number that the user selects should grab the region name at that index number (the number in the very left column) - (us-east-1, us-west-2, etc.). I tried `dataframe.iloc[region:0]` where region is the index number (from the user), but I'm getting an "Empty DataFrame" message, and the region name is not returned for some reason. Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Region, Opt-in Status]
Index: []

Comment: Sorry - I made a mistake with the index syntax. I've updated my answer with the corrections.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a row using the `.loc` function

```
dataframe.loc[int(region)]
```

in some cases you will want to use `iloc`

The `loc` function let you access the row by index (label).
The `iloc` function let you access the row by position.
You can read more about the different (with examples) [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.02-data-indexing-and-selection.html#Indexers:-loc,-iloc,-and-ix)

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in dataframe['Region']:
    if(x.split('-')[-1] == input:
        print(x)
        break
```

I think this should do what you want. But the problem is that you have more than one regions with the same end number.

If you want all the regions, you could do this:

```
li = []
for x in dataframe['Region']:
    if(x.split('-')[-1] == input:
    li.append(x)
print(li)
```